# PHP using includes to drop information into a send mail script

Tags: php, include

I'm getting a header error while trying to add a line of code to a sendmail script.

I'm guessing I'm using the wrong method to do this.

What's the best way to bring in data such as an email address into a sendmail script with out getting the header error?

See code below, I want to pull in the formmail@test.com from a .php file to all the forms on the site.  But includes causes a header error.

Thanks in advance.

Code Snipet:

```
<?php

$sitename = "Form from test.com";

$message = "This message was sent from: $sitename\n


mail( "formmail@test.com", $sitename, $message, "From: contactForm@test.com" );


  header( "Location: http://test.com/thankyou.php" );
?>
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the "already sent" error?  Also, you have a syntax error after `$message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a common error, you might have a blank line at the end of your include so your webserver send the headers and your cannot use `header('Location:')` anymore.

There is few solutions

- don't close the php tags in your headers
- enable the [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) on your server

The first solution would be the best in my opinion

Comment: +1 on the not including the close tags in include files, because this is a universal solution and doesn't have any sort of unpredictable consequences.  It is, IMHO, a best practice when working with code-only files in PHP.